# Can't save Arraylist state on fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, arraylist, state

sorry for bringing another question.

I've tried to solve by my own, but I can't.

I want to save the state from a Arraylist from a fragment inside an Activity. Basically, it's a JSON that populates by PHP script a List in a ListFragment. Then, the item clicked sends the Name and Details from the clicked item.

Finally, when the user hits the button "Add to cart", those data goes to a Arraylist in the third fragment at the same Activity.

The code:

**PedidosFragment.java**

```
package com.example.waitersoriginal;

*some imports*

public class PedidosFragment extends ListFragment{

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listaPedidos;

    private static final String TAG_NM = "NOME";
    private static final String TAG_DS = "DESCR";

    ListAdapter adapter2;

    public PedidosFragment(){}

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        //abc = savedInstanceState;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        restore(savedInstanceState);

        listaPedidos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), listaPedidos,
                R.layout.list_item, 
                new String[] { TAG_NM, TAG_DS}, 
                new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.pid});

        setListAdapter(adapter2);

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pedidos_fragment, container, false); 
    }

    void criaArray(String nomeProd, String descrProd) {


        HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();           
        map3.put(TAG_NM, nomeProd);
        map3.put(TAG_DS, descrProd);

        listaPedidos.add(map3);    

            //getListView();
            ((BaseAdapter) adapter2).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }   

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("listaPedidos", listaPedidos);
    }

    private void restore(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            listaPedidos = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("listaPedidos"); 
        }
    }

}
```

When I leave the actual activity and enter again, the Arraylist has gone. What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT:

Changing onCreateView with the suggestion given:

```
public PedidosFragment(){}

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        //abc = savedInstanceState;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        listaPedidos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        restore(savedInstanceState);

        adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), listaPedidos,
                R.layout.list_item, 
                new String[] { TAG_NM, TAG_DS}, 
                new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.pid});

        setListAdapter(adapter2);

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pedidos_fragment, container, false); 
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by leaving? Pressing the back button?

Comment: If you want to keep the items even after `onDestroyed` has been called on you activity, you'll have to save them on the device. You can use preferences, a sqlite database or object serialization to do so.

Comment: Thanks, @DuZi! But, Am I not working with object serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your restored list with a new list. Move your call to restore below the line where you instantiate listaPedidos:

```
listaPedidos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
restore(savedInstanceState);
```

However, as [@DuZi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149780/duzi) mentioned in their comment, destroying the activity will not save the instance state. From the Android documentation:

> When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the
>   activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity
>   instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity
>   is no longer needed. However, if the system destroys the activity due
>   to system constraints (rather than normal app behavior), then although
>   the actual Activity instance is gone, the system remembers that it
>   existed such that if the user navigates back to it, the system creates
>   a new instance of the activity using a set of saved data that
>   describes the state of the activity when it was destroyed. The saved
>   data that the system uses to restore the previous state is called the
>   "instance state" and is a collection of key-value pairs stored in a
>   Bundle object.

So, you will need to handle the saving & loading of this data yourself. You can put a serializable object into a string preference like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
try {
    editor.putString("listaPedidos", ObjectSerializer.serialize(listaPedidos));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
editor.commit();
```

And reload the data like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

try {
    listaPedidos= (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString("listaPedidos", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>())));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can get the ObjectSerializer class from the Apache Pig project: [ObjectSerializer.java](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Justin Powell! I've did what u suggested, but, the arraylist still renews when I press the Back button and enter in the Activity again.. Do you have any suggestion? I've made like that (question EDIT)

Comment: Thank you and @DuZi for your help!! I'm pretty newbie in android development, so I'm bit confused with implementing this code.. I've created a class ObjectSerializer.. may I need to create PreferenceManager too? Sorry for this dumb question and thanks!

Comment: No, ObjectSerializer & PreferenceManager already exist, you just need to import them to use in your code.

Comment: Oh.. is there any casting I need to do in the call? Because the Eclipse is giving an error in the lines SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); (Error: The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Conext) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (PedidosFragment) )      and in the line editor.putString("listaPedidos", ObjectSerializer.serialize(listaPedidos));  the error (ObjectSerializer cannot be resolved)..

Comment: My apologies, ObjectSerializer is not native Android. See my update. Also, `this` is just a context, you can use `getActivity()` from a fragment.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!! It worked! But, I've get another ObjectSerializer.java on the web.. when I used from the pig, it conflicts in LogFactory import and WrapIOException..  thank you and my apologies for my low knowledge with Android and these lot of questions asked..